# network Monitoring (2g and 3g ...can still bluetooth)

Tags: android, networking, monitoring

how to monitor the switching android 3g and 2g. WiFi I have done so

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int i =wifi.getWifiState();
String s; 
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                s="disabled";
                break;
            case 3:
                s="enabled";
                break;
            default:
                s="";
                break;
        }
```

Comment: so what doesnt work? What errors do you get?

Comment: not errors, I do not know how to do the same for 3g and 2g.
And 3g and 2g separately